# Getting "Wanted but not invoked" when running unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Trying to test repository method, but my test fails with following "Wanted but not invoked: cellphonesDao.deleteAllCellphones();"
Here is repo method:

```
@Override
    public Single<Cellphone[]> getCellphones() {
        Single<CellPhoneEntity[]> remoteCellphones =
            networkModule.productApi()
                .getCellPhones()
                .onErrorResumeNext(cellphonesDao.getAllCellphones()); // todo return value if true
        Single<CellPhoneEntity[]> localCellphones = cellphonesDao.getAllCellphones();

        return Single.zip(remoteCellphones, localCellphones, (remote, local) -> {
            if (!Arrays.equals(remote, local)) {
                cellphonesDao.deleteAllCellphones();
                for (CellPhoneEntity cellPhoneEntity : remote) {
                    cellphonesDao.insertCellphone(cellPhoneEntity);
                }
            }

            return mapper.toCellphones(remote);
        });
    }
```

Main porpuse is to test repo method in correct way. Guess the way I chose is not good.
Here is test implementation:

```
class CellPhoneRepositoryImplTest {
    NetworkModule networkModule;
    CellphonesDao cellphonesDao;
    CellphoneMapper cellphoneMapper;
    CellPhoneRepositoryImpl cellPhoneRepository;
    ProductAPI productAPI;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        networkModule = Mockito.mock(NetworkModule.class);
        cellphonesDao = Mockito.mock(CellphonesDao.class);
        productAPI = Mockito.mock(ProductAPI.class);
        cellphoneMapper = new CellphoneMapper();
        cellPhoneRepository = Mockito.spy(new CellPhoneRepositoryImpl(
            networkModule,
            cellphonesDao,
            cellphoneMapper
        ));
    }

    @Test
    void whenRemoteDataAreDifferentFromLocalDbIsUpdated() {
        int numberOfCellphones = 5;
        CellPhoneEntity[] remoteCellphones = DummyCellphoneEntityFactory.generateCellphones(numberOfCellphones);
        CellPhoneEntity[] localCellphones = DummyCellphoneEntityFactory.generateCellphones(numberOfCellphones);

        Mockito.when(networkModule.productApi()).thenReturn(productAPI);
        Mockito.when(networkModule.productApi().getCellPhones()).thenReturn(wrapWithSingle(remoteCellphones));
//        Mockito.when(networkModule.productApi().getCellPhones().onErrorResumeNext(cellphonesDao.getAllCellphones())).thenReturn(wrapWithSingle(remoteCellphones));
        Mockito.when(cellphonesDao.getAllCellphones()).thenReturn(wrapWithSingle(localCellphones));

        Mockito.doNothing().when(cellphonesDao).deleteAllCellphones();

        cellPhoneRepository.getCellphones();
        Mockito.verify(cellphonesDao, Mockito.times(1))
            .deleteAllCellphones();
    }

    private Single<CellPhoneEntity[]> wrapWithSingle(CellPhoneEntity[] cellphones) {
        return Single.just(cellphones);
    }
}
```

I will be glad for any suggestion)

Comment: The code inside the returned `Single` isn't executed immediately, but your verifications are. Try calling `cellPhoneRepository.getCellphones().blockingGet()` instead of just `cellPhoneRepository.getCellphones()`. The `blockingGet()` should make your test wait until the `Single` is done executing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @RobSpoor Can you please add your comment as an answer. It was really helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the returned `Single` isn't executed immediately, but your verifications are. Try calling `cellPhoneRepository.getCellphones().blockingGet()` instead of just `cellPhoneRepository.getCellphones()`. The `blockingGet()` should make your test wait until the Single is done executing.